# Why can role icons be obtained by champions who shouldn't play a certain role?

Tags: league-of-legends

What I mean by the question: in order to get all six Teambuilder icons you have to play each role for five times. At the moment I have three of them and I'm about to collect them all.

But one thing is bothering me. If I, for example, need the Marksman icon but I don't want to play the marksman role I can just pick Gnar for top lane and select that my role is Marksman even though I am not playing one.

So basically it's possible to get the Marksman icon by selecting the Marksman role, while Gnar isn't a Marksman at all and shouldn't be played like that. Why is that so?

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to select the role marksman and pick Gnar to get the marksman icon? Or are you asking why you still get the icon when you are using Gnar as Marksman?

Comment: I was a bit unclear, I update my question.

Comment: Because who determines what a marksman is? Or who determines what a Jungler is? It is a good system but not flawless.

Comment: I guess you're right. But I find it a bit obnoxious that a Xerath can select the Marksman role but just builds as a Mage on mid lane in order to get the icon. Also, I was talking about roles, jungle is a position, not a role.

Comment: However he'll end up with a strange team composition unless he's careful.

Comment: Shouldn't the title be: Why can role icons be obtained by champions who shouldn't play a certain role? Then it's more logical with the rest of the question.

Comment: @Damek with the title change combined with OPs comments this question is very borderline "a rant in disguise", as well as unanswerable without insight into the developer's minds, and should be downvoted and/or closed.

Comment: Saying you want to go Marksman mid or top may affect how long it takes you to find a team. Very few teams are looking for a marksman to go top.

Comment: @MrLemon I know, I flagged the question but it was declined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit off-topic as it asks for Game Design, but we can give possible scenarios.

I suppose that if we don't have each role for each champion, the system replacing it would be a set list of roles depending on the champion.

Look at champions like Master Yi, he always was an AD assassin, then suddenly an AP build rose and it became so powerful that it was removed from the game a season later, who would expect that ? So, imagine if you had only a set list of roles for each champion, Riot would have to spend way too much time (therefore money) to keep it updated as Meta is evolving fast and as players discover new things (sometimes unexpected by the developers) when new patches come out.

A totally different reason that is true since the beginning of this game is that some people like to play champions the "non-usual" way, whether it is for fun, or to try new things (ex: AD Ahri, full AP Amumu, etc.). So, if one day you want to play an AD carry Xerath to have fun, you can ! It is present in his rolelist with the actual system.

In conclusion, it just gives more freedom to players, and easier access to icons.

Comment: I understand what you're saying here. But what I really mean is, that it's actually possible to just play a "meta" Orianna mid lane building like a normal Mage, but selecting the Tank role just in order to get that icon. That's the only thing that bothers me, that's all.

Comment: @Praetorae Obviously, every design has his downsides. And this is one of those for the team builder. There is no way for the game to predict which items you'll buy and therefore confirming if you chose the right role or not.